# Uses for Automatic Differentiation in Investment Banking

Tags: automatic-differentiation

I've finally wrapped my head around the advantages and disadvantages of AD/AAD compared to FD and SD, but could someone please explain to me where you'd use AD/AAD in an investment bank/banking generally?

If this question has already been answered, feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: calculation of the "Greeks"

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/autodiff.html#math_toolkit.autodiff.example-black_scholes

Comment: FD is probably 'finite differences', but what is SD?

Comment: @Nachiket Symbolic differentiation, I assume.

Comment: Cheers guys, I really appreciate the above! And yes, by SD I meant Symbolic Differentiation (Investment Banking acronymization is clearly rubbing off on me!)

Comment: All neural network learning is essentially an application of automatic differentiation, usually backward, sometimes bidirectional for second derivatives.

Comment: Look for M. Giles *"Smoking adjoints"* (2006) for a (the first?) paper on computing Greeks using AD.